# how to find all possible circles in a coordinate space that pass through two points namely (0, 1) and (2, 0), with a changing Radius

Tags: functions

Given a circle, that pass through two arbitrary points, How can I get a generalized function that puts all of the possible variables of a circle that specifically passes through two points?

In this case, the circle formula $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$ harbors three variables that could change.

Is there a functional relation between $h$, $k$ and $r$ that I can represent algebraically that passes through those two points? That is my question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just wanted a generalized function between the three unknown variables in which case only the three variables when put in a function will output a circle that passes through those two points.

Comment: The centre $(h,k)$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of the two given points, and $r$ can be solved by your circle formula.

Comment: I would like for cases in which it is also not a perpendicular bisector @peterwhy

Comment: @Fushi There are no such cases. The centre of a circle always lies on the perpendicular bisector of any given chord.

Comment: @peterwhy I think I should retort what I am trying to attempt. I want a function that gets all of the circles that lies within (0, 1) and (2, 0) You can check out my attempt of doing this in this desmos graph, though it only works for only one point only, I just want to extend this to two points

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/spxq4xezta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are aware of the concept of family of circles. 
The equation of a family of circles passing through two points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ is given by:
$(x-x_1)(x-x_2) + (y-y_1)(y-y_2) + \alpha\begin{vmatrix}
     x & y & 1\\ 
     x_{1} & y_{1} & 1\\
     x_{2} & y_{2} & 1 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept, but it seems like this is the solution that I might be looking for. I would need to study more about it though.
Thanks

Comment: @Fushi___ A family of circles represents all the circles satisfying a given condition. So in this case, the above equation is the equation of all circles passing through two points.